# Change of variable for a weak derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $h \in C([0,T], \mathbb R) \cap W^{1, \infty}([0,T], \mathbb R)$ such that the following estimate is satisfied
$$\frac{h'(t)}{h(t)^{3/2}} \le C f(t)$$
for $h'$ the (weak) derivative of $h$ and $f$ some function in $L^1(0,T)$. If everything were smooth, I could integrate on both side of the inequality and get
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{h(T)}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{h(0)}} = \int_0^T\frac{h'(t)}{h(t)^{3/2}} \le C \|f\|_{L^1(0,T)}.$$
However, here we are working in Sobolev spaces so I cannot integrate the left hand side as I did. Is there a way to treat this problem in the case of Sobolev spaces ?

Comment: You might add that $h$ has its values in$\mathbb{R}^+$. Now $h$ being in $W^{1,\infty}$ its weak derivative is in $L^\infty$ thus integrable on a bounded set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $h(t) \ge c > 0$ for all $t$. Then $t\mapsto \frac1{\sqrt t}$ is $C^1$ on the range of $h$, i.e., on $[c, \|h\|_\infty]$. We can extend it to a smooth function $\phi$ on $\mathbb R$. Then $\phi(h)$ is in $C([0,T]) \cap W^{1,\infty}(0,T)$. And the calculation you did is valid.

Comment: Great thanks! And to conclude we have to use some kind of fundamental theorem of calculus for weak derivative?